# Alignment of conditions between dcases (or cases) environments

Tags: cases, mathtools

I have found various discussions/questions on this subject, but I haven't found one that answers my question in a understandable way.

How do I align the conditions of multiple piecewise equations?

I.e.: in the following code, how do I align the `&`-symbols across the various `dcases` environments, within the single `align` environment? I believe it isn't of importance, but the equations are within a `subequations` environment.

Please explain how your solution works, so I can better understand how LaTeX aligns the pieces of math using your code. Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align}
            \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial MPO} &= 1, \quad &\forall x, \\
            \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial L_1} &= 
            \begin{dcases}
                \frac{1}{\rho} - 1, \quad & x<L_1 \\
                0, \quad & \text{otherwise,}
            \end{dcases} \\
            \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial L_2} &= 
            \begin{dcases}
                -\frac{1}{\rho}, \quad & x<L_2 \\
                0, \quad & \text{otherwise,}
            \end{dcases}\\
            \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial \rho} &=
            \begin{dcases}
                \frac{L_2-L_2}{\rho^2}, \quad & x<L_1 \\
                \frac{L_2-x}{\rho^2}, \quad & L_1\leq x<L_2\\
                0, \quad & \text{otherwise.}
            \end{dcases}
        \end{align}
    \end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) you do not need those quads. (2) I usually use `\mathmakebox` to make one of the entries of each cases a certain size. Which the right width this will align the conditions. The cases ends does not communicate so you need a manual solution

Comment: @daleif thanks. @(1) I need at least one after the longest line for a bit more spacing (aesthetics) between case and condition @(2) I will look into it and answer my own question if I find a compact way of solving the problem.

Comment: Dcases can be generally reset with a larger gap.

Comment: Thanks again. How do I do that? And I get cryptic errors when I make one of the case lines within a `\makemathbox[width][pos]{math}`.

Comment: It should be in the manual, otherwise look in the sty file. Regarding the other one, remember use it on the cell, do not include the &, otherwise please update your question with a failing mwe

Comment: That was indeed the cause of the errors. Thanks for pointing that out! It works now, but it is not elegant. I'll post the answer later when I have time, if I remember. Is it possible to request the `mathtools` developer(s) to implement a different `&`-symbol, that ranges to a higher level? Maybe a command that aligns to any number of higher levels. This way you can really take control of any complex sub-alignment.

Comment: I think nath can do this, but it is incompatible with almost everything. I do not think it is worth it. Would also require an amsmath rewrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an MWE answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\cl}{.2\textwidth} % cl: custom length for the makemathboxes
    \begin{align}
        x & =
        \begin{dcases}
            \mathmakebox[\cl][l]{
                y,
                }
                \text{foo,} \\
            \mathmakebox[\cl][l]{
                y + z,
                }
                \text{foobar,}
        \end{dcases} \\
        y -z & =
        \begin{dcases}
            \mathmakebox[\cl][l]{
                123,
                }
                \text{foofoobar,} \\
            \mathmakebox[\cl][l]{
                9876543210,
                }
                a<b,
        \end{dcases} \\
        x - y + z & =
        % \smash{
        % \phantom{\begin{dcases}\null\\\null\end{dcases}} % without this, the \sin{\phi} doesn't indent to the dcases environments
        % }
        % the 3 lines above or the following line have more or less the same effect (the line below is better)
        \mkern15mu
        \mathmakebox[\cl][l]{
        \sin(\phi),
        }
        \phi\geq\theta. % note this looks minimally disaligned with the dcases environments
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

A little more could be put into a new command, but it works. Note the comments.

Comment: You may want to encase the instructions  `\phantom{\begin{dcases}\null\\\null\end{dcases}}` in a `\smash` directive in order to get rid of the extra vertical space that's otherwise inserted both above and below the line in question. The alignment still isn't perfect, though. I'd be tempted to just insert `\mkern15mu` between `& =` and `\sin\phi`. Incidentally, there's no advantage (from a typopgrahpic point of view) in typing `\sin{\phi}`.

Comment: @Mico indeed, it should have been `\sin\phi` or what I intended to write: `\sin(\phi)`. What is the `\mkern15mu`? Additional white space instead of the `\phantom{...}`? And why 15µ?

Comment: I've implemented your suggestions. The 15µ is exactly the needed horizontal skip. It is even better than the smashed phantom, which was a little too large. Why is it 15µ? Is this the default width of the large "{", and does this work across different math fonts? Thanks!

Comment: @Erik `mu` is the name of an internal unit of TeX and stands for “mathematical unit”; its value is such that 18mu are 1em in the current symbol font.

Comment: @egreg thanks, however it doesn't answer my question: Why is it `15mu` in this case? How do you know? Just try a length and see if it is correct? And this leads to another question: Can all or most math lengths be expressed in an integer `mu` length, e.g. the space between `x`_`=`_`y` or between `(`_`x`_`)`, etc.?

Comment: @Erik I guess that 15mu was computed by trial and error; the space around math relations is `\thickmuskip`, which usually has a natural component that's an integer number of mu units, but it need not.

Comment: The value of `15mu` was indeed obtained by trial, but without too much error... The value of `\thickmuskip` is `5mu` in the standard document classes, and my initial guess was that the width of the curly braces would come to about `5mu`. Total width to be skipped therefore `15mu` -- which turns out to be  more or less correct... :-)